# Word for the type of structure/category where each automorphism on an object corresponds to a different object?

Tags: category-theory, automorphism-group

In a given category, if I have an object $x$ whose automorphism group $\operatorname{Aut}\left(x\right)$ has order $k$, I would expect there to be exactly $k$ at least definitionally distinct objects in that category which are isomorphic to $x$ (including $x$ itself).

However, if we take e.g. the one-object representation of a group, every morphism is an automorphism, but there is only one object.

Is there a term for categories that do vs don't collapse isomorphic objects? (I stumbled across the terms "looping" and "delooping", but [the nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/looping) looked like alphabet soup.)

Comment: Why would you expect that? As you've already noted, it's not true. And what does "definitionally distinct" mean? For example, in the category of sets a finite set of size $n$ has an automorphism group of size $n!$, and there are way more than $n!$ finite sets of size $n$; in fact there are so many that they don't form a set.

Comment: What we can say in the finite set case is that a finite set of size $n$ has $n!$ total orders on it, and the automorphism group acts freely and transitively on these total orders. Is this the sort of thing you mean? This doesn't really have anything to do with "definitionally distinct objects" though.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for the reply. I meant that I initially had thought that would be the case, before realizing there were counterexamples.

Actually, I think a preorder/thin category may be a better way to have this restriction, because what I was originally envisioning (one isomorphic object per automorphism) may overly muddle the idea of equality/inequality. So then the one-object vs thin representations of some structure are just the fully collapsed vs expanded forms.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh, and by definitionally distinct I meant objects that are different _a priori_, yet isomorphic, like how $3+8$ and $2+9$ are distinct terms, but represent the same thing.

Comment: Regarding terminology, a category is called [skeletal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_(category_theory)) if isomorphic objects are necessarily equal. Relatedly, a category is called [gaunt](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/gaunt+category) if every isomorphism is an identity morphism.

Comment: Thanks @varkor. It seems like there's a spectrum of granularity with thin/preorder on one end and one-object on the other, with skeletal in between. And gauntness would be an incidental property that doesn't lie on that spectrum.

Comment: I think every object in $\textbf{Cat}$ whose only incoming morphisms are isomorphisms would be a thin category, and every object whose only outgoing morphisms are isomorphisms would be a one-object category or the empty category. So the spectrum of granularity is just chains of category homomorphisms, as would be expected.